# Loading html table static rows on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below html table.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<table cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Student01</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student02</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>88</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student03</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student05</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>68</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student06</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>99</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student07</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>68</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student08</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student09</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student10</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student11</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>86</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student12</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>85</td>
        </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Above html table has 12 rows but usually it can contain upto 100 static rows. I dont want to render all the hundered rows at once.  But i have to display only 10 rows at a time and when user scrolls the vertical scroll bar then again i need to add 10 more rows to the existing 10 rows and so on...

Basically i have all static html rows and i need to render few and add few more on scroll...

How can i do it using `JQuery` ?

Comment: Like **[THIS](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid27.php)** ?

Comment: Batu Zet, i dont want to get the data from server. I have a static html table with 100 rows..

Comment: He asks if it is the same mechanism I think. You can see how it works and make your own to load from static variable or any other source.

Comment: Rolice, i have a HTML Static table with 100 rows....

Comment: If you were kind enough to check the link i gave you properly and view the demo, you would've seen that there's an option there to load _local data_.

Comment: Why would you want to do this then? If the rows are statically in the html, they get parsed by the broswer anyway; you're not getting any performance boost. And rendering already parsed 100 rows of a table takes time in milliseconds for a modern browser.

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/U5L86/ ?